# Переключение между окнами приложения QStackedWidget

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

Как правильно было бы реализовать переключение между окнами приложениями? Ведь сейчас оно выглядит не наилучшим образом.

То, как это реализовано сейчас :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


# классы Ui отвечают за шаблон графического интерфейса
# ! не изменять, если вы не знаете что вы делаете
class Ui_Win1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win1):
        Win1.setObjectName("Win1")
        Win1.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win1)
        self.widgetWin1.setObjectName("widgetWin1")
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin1)
        self.text1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text1.setObjectName("text1")
        self.bnt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin1)
        self.bnt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt.setObjectName("bnt")
        self.bnt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin1)
        self.bnt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt_2.setObjectName("bnt_2")
        self.bnt_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin1)
        self.bnt_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt_3.setObjectName("bnt_3")
        Win1.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin1)

        self.retranslateUi(Win1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win1)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win1.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win1", "MainWindow"))
        self.text1.setText(_translate("Win1", "Win1"))
        self.bnt.setText(_translate("Win1", "1"))
        self.bnt_2.setText(_translate("Win1", "2"))
        self.bnt_3.setText(_translate("Win1", "3"))


class Ui_Win2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win2):
        Win2.setObjectName("Win2")
        Win2.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win2)
        self.widgetWin2.setObjectName("widgetWin2")
        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin2)
        self.text2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text2.setObjectName("text2")
        self.bnt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin2)
        self.bnt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt.setObjectName("bnt")
        self.bnt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin2)
        self.bnt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt_2.setObjectName("bnt_2")
        self.bnt_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin2)
        self.bnt_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt_3.setObjectName("bnt_3")
        Win2.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin2)

        self.retranslateUi(Win2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win2)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win2", "MainWindow"))
        self.text2.setText(_translate("Win2", "Win2"))
        self.bnt.setText(_translate("Win2", "1"))
        self.bnt_2.setText(_translate("Win2", "2"))
        self.bnt_3.setText(_translate("Win2", "3"))


class Ui_Win3(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win3):
        Win3.setObjectName("Win3")
        Win3.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win3)
        self.widgetWin3.setObjectName("widgetWin3")
        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin3)
        self.text3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text3.setObjectName("text3")
        self.bnt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin3)
        self.bnt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt.setObjectName("bnt")
        self.bnt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin3)
        self.bnt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt_2.setObjectName("bnt_2")
        self.bnt_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetWin3)
        self.bnt_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt_3.setObjectName("bnt_3")
        Win3.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin3)

        self.retranslateUi(Win3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win3)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win3):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win3.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win3", "MainWindow"))
        self.text3.setText(_translate("Win3", "Win3"))
        self.bnt.setText(_translate("Win3", "1"))
        self.bnt_2.setText(_translate("Win3", "2"))
        self.bnt_3.setText(_translate("Win3", "3"))


# Функциональные классы наследуют виджеты классов Ui
class Win1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win1):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.stacked = self.parent.stacked

        self.bnt.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.bnt_2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.bnt_3.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2))


class Win2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win2):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.stacked = self.parent.stacked

        self.bnt.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.bnt_2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.bnt_3.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2))


class Win3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win3):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.stacked = self.parent.stacked

        self.bnt.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.bnt_2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.bnt_3.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked)

        self.Window_Win1 = Win1(self)
        self.Window_Win2 = Win2(self)
        self.Window_Win3 = Win3(self)

        self.stacked.addWidget(self.Window_Win1)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.Window_Win2)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.Window_Win3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(450, 800)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Здесь повторяется одна и та же конструкция во всех функциональных классах, что не есть хорошо и я добавил во все **`Ui`** классы кнопки для упрощение конструкции, в место множественного наследия, что тоже не есть хорошо.

Как я мог бы это исправить и то как надо было бы это сделать ?

**Ui** классы :

```
class Ui_Win1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win1):
        Win1.setObjectName("Win1")
        Win1.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win1)
        self.widgetWin1.setObjectName("widgetWin1")
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin1)
        self.text1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text1.setObjectName("text1")
        Win1.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin1)

        self.retranslateUi(Win1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win1)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win1.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win1", "MainWindow"))
        self.text1.setText(_translate("Win1", "Win1"))


class Ui_Win2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win2):
        Win2.setObjectName("Win2")
        Win2.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win2)
        self.widgetWin2.setObjectName("widgetWin2")
        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin2)
        self.text2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text2.setObjectName("text2")
        Win2.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin2)

        self.retranslateUi(Win2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win2)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win2", "MainWindow"))
        self.text2.setText(_translate("Win2", "Win2"))


class Ui_Win3(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win3):
        Win3.setObjectName("Win3")
        Win3.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win3)
        self.widgetWin3.setObjectName("widgetWin3")
        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin3)
        self.text3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text3.setObjectName("text3")
        Win3.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin3)

        self.retranslateUi(Win3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win3)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win3):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win3.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win3", "MainWindow"))
        self.text3.setText(_translate("Win3", "Win3"))


class Ui_Bnt(object):
    def setupUi(self, Bnt):
        Bnt.setObjectName("Bnt")
        Bnt.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetBnt = QtWidgets.QWidget(Bnt)
        self.widgetBnt.setObjectName("widgetBnt")
        self.bnt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetBnt)
        self.bnt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt.setObjectName("bnt")
        self.bnt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetBnt)
        self.bnt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt_2.setObjectName("bnt_2")
        self.bnt_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widgetBnt)
        self.bnt_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 772, 150, 28))
        self.bnt_3.setObjectName("bnt_3")
        Bnt.setCentralWidget(self.widgetBnt)

        self.retranslateUi(Bnt)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Bnt)

    def retranslateUi(self, Bnt):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Bnt.setWindowTitle(_translate("Bnt", "MainWindow"))
        self.bnt.setText(_translate("Bnt", "1"))
        self.bnt_2.setText(_translate("Bnt", "2"))
        self.bnt_3.setText(_translate("Bnt", "3"))
```

Примечание:
Без использования QLayout и заменены кнопок на что то другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Win1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win1):
        Win1.setObjectName("Win1")
        Win1.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win1)
        self.widgetWin1.setObjectName("widgetWin1")
        
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin1)
        self.text1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text1.setObjectName("text1")

        Win1.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin1)
        self.retranslateUi(Win1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win1)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win1.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win1", "MainWindow"))
        self.text1.setText(_translate("Win1", "Win1"))


class Ui_Win2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win2):
        Win2.setObjectName("Win2")
        Win2.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win2)
        self.widgetWin2.setObjectName("widgetWin2")
        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin2)
        self.text2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text2.setObjectName("text2")

        Win2.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin2)
        self.retranslateUi(Win2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win2)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win2", "MainWindow"))
        self.text2.setText(_translate("Win2", "Win2"))


class Ui_Win3(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win3):
        Win3.setObjectName("Win3")
        Win3.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win3)
        self.widgetWin3.setObjectName("widgetWin3")
        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin3)
        self.text3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text3.setObjectName("text3")

        Win3.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin3)

        self.retranslateUi(Win3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win3)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win3):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win3.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win3", "MainWindow"))
        self.text3.setText(_translate("Win3", "Win3"))


class Win1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win1):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Win2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win2):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Win3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win3):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class VLine(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VLine, self).__init__()
        self.setFrameShape(self.VLine|self.Sunken)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked)

        self.window_Win1 = Win1(self)
        self.window_Win2 = Win2(self)
        self.window_Win3 = Win3(self)

        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window_Win1)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window_Win2)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window_Win3)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.statusBar().showMessage("bla-bla bla")
        
        self.bnt = QtWidgets.QPushButton('bnt')
        self.bnt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('bnt_2')
        self.bnt_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('bnt_3')
        
        self.bnt.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.bnt_2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.bnt_3.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2))
        
        self.statusBar().reformat()
        self.statusBar().setStyleSheet('border: 0; background-color: #FFF8DC;')
        self.statusBar().setStyleSheet("QStatusBar::item {border: none;}") 
        
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())    
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.bnt)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())    
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.bnt_2)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())    
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.bnt_3)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(450, 600)                        # <---- (450, 800)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> мне не нравиться то что они находиться в строке состояния

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Win1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win1):
        Win1.setObjectName("Win1")
        Win1.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win1)
        self.widgetWin1.setObjectName("widgetWin1")
        
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin1)
        self.text1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text1.setObjectName("text1")

        Win1.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin1)
        self.retranslateUi(Win1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win1)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win1.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win1", "MainWindow"))
        self.text1.setText(_translate("Win1", "Win1"))


class Ui_Win2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win2):
        Win2.setObjectName("Win2")
        Win2.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win2)
        self.widgetWin2.setObjectName("widgetWin2")
        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin2)
        self.text2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text2.setObjectName("text2")

        Win2.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin2)
        self.retranslateUi(Win2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win2)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win2", "MainWindow"))
        self.text2.setText(_translate("Win2", "Win2"))


class Ui_Win3(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win3):
        Win3.setObjectName("Win3")
        Win3.resize(450, 800)
        self.widgetWin3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win3)
        self.widgetWin3.setObjectName("widgetWin3")
        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widgetWin3)
        self.text3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(197, 378, 56, 16))
        self.text3.setObjectName("text3")

        Win3.setCentralWidget(self.widgetWin3)

        self.retranslateUi(Win3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win3)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win3):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win3.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win3", "MainWindow"))
        self.text3.setText(_translate("Win3", "Win3"))


class Win1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win1):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Win2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win2):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Win3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Win3):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Win3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked)

        self.window_Win1 = Win1(self)
        self.window_Win1.setStyleSheet('#Win1 {background-color: #ffbdcc;}') 
        self.window_Win2 = Win2(self)
        self.window_Win2.setStyleSheet('#Win2 {background-color: #ccffbd;}') 
        self.window_Win3 = Win3(self)
        self.window_Win3.setStyleSheet('#Win3 {background-color: #bdccccff;}') 

        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window_Win1)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window_Win2)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window_Win3)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        self.create_buttons(self.window_Win1)
        
    def create_buttons(self, parent):       
        bnt = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Win1", parent)
#        self.bnt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 772, 150, 28)) # установите свою геометрию
        bnt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 572, 150, 28))
        
        bnt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Win2", parent)
#        self.bnt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 772, 150, 28))
        bnt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 572, 150, 28))
        
        bnt_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Win3", parent)
#        self.bnt_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 772, 150, 28))
        bnt_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 572, 150, 28))
        
        bnt.clicked.connect(self.go_win1)
        bnt_2.clicked.connect(self.go_win2)
        bnt_3.clicked.connect(self.go_win3)
        bnt.show()
        bnt_2.show()
        bnt_3.show()
        
    def go_win1(self):
        self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.create_buttons(self.window_Win1)
        
    def go_win2(self):
        self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.create_buttons(self.window_Win2)  
        
    def go_win3(self):
        self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.create_buttons(self.window_Win3)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(450, 650)                        # <---- (450, 800)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вы создали строку состояния ```statusBar()``` ? Кнопки же тогда будут привязаны к нему и будут изменять свой размер при изменении размера окна. (можно задать им фиксированный размер но это не то) Также я не смогу их свободно размещать по окну, и если у кнопок ранее уже был стиль то мне придется прописывать его и в ```statusBar()```. Я знал что так сделать можно но не делал потому что мне это не подходило. Я хотел чтобы кнопки находились непосредственно в окне но как это сделать кроме как я сделал в примере не придумал

Comment: @assert я уже не совсем понимаю что вам нужно и чем вам можно помочь. Попробуйте объяснить лучше и возможно продемонстрировать на изображении что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Я хочу переключаться между окнами приложении с помощью кнопок, пример того как это выглядеть в примере. В примере меня не устраивает что кнопки мне пришлось добавить во все Ui классы и для переключения между окнами прописывать одну и туже конструкцию в функциональных окнах

Comment: @assert так я же убрал во всех Ui классах кнопки и оставил их в одном месте и вы свободно можете переключаться между окнами используя эти кнопки. Что не так? Вы пробовали запустить мой пример?

Comment: Я запускал ваш пример. Вы поместили кнопки в строку состояния и они стали изменять свой размер относительно окна и находятся поверх остальных окон а не непосредственно в них

Comment: Ну или иными словами мне не нравиться то что они находиться в строке состояния

Comment: @assert я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.